# knockout.js reactor how to inspect beforeWatch parameters

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

How do I use "beforeWatch"? I can see that it gives you parent and child as parameters, but how do I inspect them -- I want the childs name (the name of the observable.)

```
ko.watch(this.params, {
beforeWatch: function (parents, child) {
    if (<is the observable named 'on_hover'>)
        return false; // cancel subscription
    }
}, function (parents, child, item) {
...
});
```

Why: I don't want the **auto save** to fire when I mouse over items being watched. I do want it to run when the user changes things (auto save is throttled with _.debounce(save(), 1000)).

Comment: Your question is fine IMO, but given that GitHub repo has only one committer and hasn't been very active, you may not get too many responses here (not sure). I'd suggest either digging through the source yourself, or contacting the author (and be sure to politely ask him/her to answer here (too), so others may benefit too :D).